# O/P error in Python Inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am practicing Python Inheritance and have written this code,

```
class College:

    def __init__(self,clgName = 'KIIT'):
        self.collegename = clgName
    def showname(self):
        return(self.collegename)

class Student(College):
    def __init__(self,studentName,studentRoll):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.studentname = studentName
        self.studentroll = studentRoll
    def show(self):
        print(self.studentname,self.studentroll,self.collegename)



p = Student('ram',22)
p.show()
```

i want answer to be like `ram 22 KIIT` but its showing `ram 22 <__main__.Student object at 0x00000238972C2CC0>`

so what am i doing wrong? and how can i print desired o/p ?
please be guiding me, Thanks in advance.

@Daniel Roseman Thanks sir for clearing my doubt, so if i would like to get the same result by this way what i have to do, not its showing `super.__init__()` needs a positional argument

```
 class College:

    def __init__(self,clgName):
        self.collegename = clgName
    def showname(self):
        return(self.collegename)

class Student(College):
    def __init__(self,studentName,studentRoll):
        super().__init__()
        self.studentname = studentName
        self.studentroll = studentRoll
    def show(self):
        print(self.studentname,self.studentroll,self.collegename)


c=College('KIIT')
c.showname()
p = Student('ram',22)
p.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're explicitly passing `self` to the super `__init__` call; that is taking the place of the `clgname` parameter. You don't need to pass it there, it's just like calling any other method so `self` is passed implicitly.

```
class Student(College):
    def __init__(self,studentName,studentRoll):
        super().__init__()
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks sir, for clearing my doubt, but if i do it other-way im also having error... please have a look at my question i have update it..

Comment: Well, you've deleted the default value for collegename. So how are you expecting it to work now? Where is the collegename going to be defined?

Comment: well cant i assign clgName during calling class like `c = College('KIIT')`? Sorry,im new to python so getting confused in silly points..

Comment: Your confusion is due to the fact that you are trying to use inheritance in a place where it does not fit at all. Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship; eg a Cat class could inherit from an Animal class because a cat is an animal. But a student is *not* a college; there is no reason to use inheritance here. Instead, the Student class should accept a College instance in `__init__` and store it as `self.college`.

Comment: well, i thought every student in clg share same clg name thats why i defined clg in parent class and tried to inherit it in student class..

Comment: No, every student shares a college instance. That college should be an attribute of the student class. This is composition, not inheritance.

Comment: oh, got it, so no need of inheritance here, i can simply store it as self.college with a default value . thanks sir, for explaining it properly .